# For studying properties of natural number, do we only need to study finite set of numbers to prove a particular property?

Tags: number-theory, logic

Let's say we want to study whether the set of natural numbers satisfy a particular property. Then we may think of induction, or whatever. My question, is it true that there exists $X \in \mathbb{N}$ that if we know that property holds for $x < X$ ($x \in \mathbb{N}$), then we know that property holds for every natural number?

If so, why would this hold?

Edit: We limit our properties not to restrict on range of natural number. So no $x < 1000$ or $x=1000$ as property. Our properties are not restricted for every natural number.

Comment: You can see [Mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). You must prove that if the statement holds for all m smaller than n, then it holds for n.

Comment: I will look at it, but isn't induction about proving that if $p(x)$ is true for $x<n$, then $n$ is true, prove the base case and we know that property is true?

Comment: My case is, does a number $X$ exist that if $x<X$ then property is true? (Of course that $X$ may be different from property to property, but can existence of such number be guaranteed?)

Comment: Let $P(x)$ be "$x < 1000$". Then $P(x)$ holds e.g. for $x < X := 500$ but it does not hold for e.g. $x = 2000$.

Comment: In general : NO. Say $X = 100$; we have that for every number n less than X, $n < 10$ is *true*, but it is not true that **all** numbers are less than $10$.

Comment: I edited the question..

Comment: Ok then let $P(x)$ be "every odd integer $1 < n < x$ is prime". Then $P(x)$ holds for $x < 10$, but it is false if $x \geq 10$

Comment: You can use again $X= 100$ with : $\forall x (x < X \rightarrow \lnot 100|x)$; in this case the "property" $\phi(x) := \lnot 100|x$ is satisfied by all $n$ less than $X$ ...

Comment: What you can do is : if all *finite* subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ have the property $\phi$, then ...

Answer (score 1):

If $X\subseteq \mathbb N$ then there exists an element $x\in\mathbb N$ with $x\in X\iff X=\mathbb N$. This is a consequence of the Axiom of Extensionality in set theory - and therefore of no practical use.

However, the choice of $x$ necessarily depends on $X$ (though it is unclear what you really accept as a property - or in my reformulation: subset, as you cannot really "forbid" $<$): I shall assume that there exists a subset $X\subsetneq \mathbb N$ that you accept as given by a "valid" property (maybe $X=\emptyset$ is accepted by you). I shall also assume that if $X\subseteq \mathbb N$ is valid then $\{\,n\in\mathbb N\mid n\text{ odd}\lor \frac n2\in X\,\}$ is also valid. Then for any given $x\in\mathbb N$, after fininetly many steps we reach a proper subset of $\mathbb N$ that does contain $x$.